# Async/await in web browser or in node.js?

Tags: javascript, async-await

Is there any attempt to bring **async/await** feature from C# 5.0 to any language which can be compiled to JavaScript (such as CoffeScript)? (So it can be used either in web browser or in node.js.)

Comment: In-browser JavaScript and JavaScript via node.js have their own way of doing asynchronous programming. You'll be much better off simply learning how that works and using it as intended instead of trying to force it into a different model (which is likely to be completely impossible anyway).

Comment: @Pointy: C# 5's awaits are a syntactic wrapper around the same callback model.  They're **much** easier to use than callbacks, in any language.

Comment: OK I of course defer to your broader experience :-)

Comment: @Pointy that's not really true—JS in the browser and JS on NodeJS have fundamentally the *same* programming model, and that is the event loop plus fundamentals such as setTimeout, events, and callbacks. it just so happens that a lot (but not all) of NodeJS's asynchronous functions use callbacks, whereas in the browser it's more events. but that is just a matter of statistics and style.

Comment: @flow I didn't mean that JavaScript in the browser and in Node have their own *distinct* async models; I listed those two environments because there are others (notably Rhino) where there **are** synchronous I/O (etc) operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not familiar with C#, but it sounds like what you're looking for is some sort of continuations, so that instead of writing

```
fs.readFile 'foo.txt', (err, data) ->
  myFunc data
```

you could instead just write something like

```
data = &fs.readFile 'foo.txt'  # not a real syntax
myFunc data
```

This isn't something that JavaScript or CoffeeScript provides. However, there are several other compilers that can do something like this:

- [TameJS](http://tamejs.org/) -  JavaScript-based, mainly just adds this feature
- [Kaffeine](http://weepy.github.com/kaffeine/) - JavaScript-based, adds a bunch of features
- [coco](https://github.com/satyr/coco) - CoffeeScript-based

See also: [List of languages that compile to JavaScript](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) on the CoffeeScript wiki.

Comment: Look for "[backcall](https://github.com/satyr/coco/wiki/additions)" on the Coco wiki. It uses a `<-` operator.

Comment: May I mention that adding such a syntax to javascript has a whole set of negatives, like having to trust the compiled code, having to understand the compiled code, having to debug the compiled code and being tempted to abuse synchronous design patterns in an asynchronous environment. basically they are abstractions that will easily leak unless you know exactly what your doing and I belief only the module author and a small number of people know exactly what they are doing

Answer (score 17):

[Async](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:async_functions) is on feature list for JavaScript harmony. So far there are numerous attempts to provide such functionality in the browser or in node, none of them seem to be compatible with harmony proposal though:

- Async can be simulated with JS1.7 generators (see [task.js](http://taskjs.org/)). Not yet supported out-of-the-box by V8 ([without experimental mode](http://wingolog.org/archives/2013/05/08/generators-in-v8)), but works in FF. Possibly [traceur](http://code.google.com/p/traceur-compiler) or [Masacra](http://www.mascaraengine.com/) compiler can be used to bring generators to other environments.
- There is [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) library providing other mechanism for asynchronous programming in node (scarifies performance though). Other attempt basing on v8cgi is described [here](http://blog.asana.com/2010/10/adding-fibers-to-v8-efficiency-clarity-in-ssjs/).
- Rhino has [continuations](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/RhinoWithContinuations) out of the box providing good alternative. This is why [Ringo.js](http://www.ringojs.org/) might be worth looking at.
- Few solutions basing on js2js translation are available, e.g: [jscx](https://github.com/JeffreyZhao/jscex), [NarrativeJS](http://www.neilmix.com/narrativejs/doc/index.html), [jwacs](http://chumsley.org/jwacs/), [StratifiedJS](http://onilabs.com/stratifiedjs). Some support integration with node.
- There are many promise/future libraries trying to solve callbacks problem without extending syntax, however they all suffer from composability issues, i.e. cannot use language constructs like loops across callbacks.

Answer (score 16):

async/await looks to be [coming in ECMAScript 7](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/). This [proposal](https://github.com/lukehoban/ecmascript-asyncawait) was accepted into stage 1 of the specification process in January 2014.

The good news is that Googles [traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/LanguageFeatures#async-functions-experimental) already supports it, so you could start using it today.

Sample syntax:

```
async function asyncValue(value) {
  await timeout(50);
  return value;
}
```

async/await is also on the [TypeScript roadmap](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap).

Comment: Just in case somebody want direct link to draft proposal https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/

Comment: the wait is over with node v7.0.0, well [nearly](https://github.com/nodejs/promises/issues/4#issuecomment-251025934)

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is, and you don't even need to compile it, because it is just a simple JavaScript library.

One of my projects called sharpnr.js has the aim to extend JavaScript with great features of C# (and .NET of course) like await/async, or LINQ.

The library is currently in beta, but it's stable and supports almost every statement (for example loops, switch, if), and works well with existing libraries (like jQuery).

The await/async syntax is almost identical to the C# version:

```
var getAsync = async(function(url) {
  var result = await; $.get(url);
  $("#test").html(result);
});
getAsync("http://www.sharpnrjs.com");
```

Working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajuhos/ujh8U/).

You can download the library from [github](https://github.com/ajuhos/sharpnr.js/downloads).

Answer (score 4):

When Node 0.11 ([with v8 3.19 [1]](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/05/13/node-v0-11-2-unstable/), [which has generators[2]](http://wingolog.org/archives/2013/05/08/generators-in-v8)) arrives, you can use [Galaxy](https://github.com/bjouhier/galaxy#asyncawait-in-javascript) and code like below.

However, only behind a flag. They are [supported natively in ioJS](https://iojs.org/en/es6.html).

```
function* countLines(path) {
    var names = yield fs.readdir(path);
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var fullname = path + '/' + names[i];
        if ((yield fs.stat(fullname)).isDirectory()) {
            total += yield countLines(fullname);
        } else {
            var count = (yield fs.readFile(fullname, 'utf8')).split('\n').length;
            console.log(fullname + ': ' + count);
            total += count;
        }
    }
    return total;
}

function* projectLineCounts() {
    var total = 0;
    total += yield countLines(__dirname + '/../examples');
    total += yield countLines(__dirname + '/../lib');
    total += yield countLines(__dirname + '/../test');
    console.log('TOTAL: ' + total);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thx, for the solution in node.js and hopefully modern browsers:)

Answer (score 3):

You can have async/await in Google Chrome with Experimental JS flag enabled, using built-in Generators, Promises and a tiny [spawn() function by Jake Archibald](http://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/#until-es7-arrives):

```
spawn(function*() { //this function is async
      let story = yield getJSON('story.json'); //yield is like await
      addHtmlToPage(story.heading);
});
```

Alternatively, you can use:

- [Q with async() and spawn() by Kris Kowal](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/tree/v2/examples/async-generators)
- [Co by Visionmedia](https://github.com/visionmedia/co)
- [Awaitable by Jonathan Ong](https://github.com/thenables/awaitable)
- [Task.js by Mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/task.js)
- [Then-yield by Forbes Lindesay](https://github.com/then/yield)
- [When by cujoJS](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

For browsers not supporting ES6, there is [Facebook Regenerator](http://facebook.github.io/regenerator/).

Answer (score 3):

**good news**,

nodejs supports it from v7.0.0 (well, partially),  still need a harmony flag `--harmony_async_await`, and apparently has some bugs including memory leak, for [more details](https://github.com/nodejs/promises/issues/4#issuecomment-251025934), but there are some concerns as well, and one commentator [advises](https://github.com/nodejs/promises/issues/4#issuecomment-254159118) to wait till v8 version 55 which might not be long.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness: I have found that [Saltarelle Compiler](http://www.saltarelle-compiler.com/) (which actually compiles C# to JavaScript) also supports await/async.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in .NET style asynchronous programming for JavaScript you should look into Rx for JavaScript. Rx for JavaScrpt is Microsoft's JavaScript port of the Reactive Framework. The reactive framework is described as:

> A library to compose asynchronous and event-based programs using
>   observable collections and LINQ-style query operators.

You can download Rx for JavaScript [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577610)

And you can read more about it, including examples [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=208527)

You can also install it on node with npm:

> npm install rx

It works well with libraries like jQuery, however I am not a CoffeeScript programmer, so I'm not sure what support there is for interoperability with other JavaScript libraries in this language.

Comment: Does Rx for JavaScript provide the async/await feature?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is providing async-await feature with ECMA 7. Now all asynchronous function can be awaited by promisifying them and waiting for promise to resolve. Most of the asynchronous functions like DB calls, API calls, fs and events are returning promise now in Javascript and nodeJs. Now with async-await code is more cleaner, understandable, debugged.

Example

```
function timeout(){
  return new Promise( resolve => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve(true);
    }, 5000);
  });
}

async function f(){
    let result = await timeout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is https://github.com/loveencounterflow/coffy-script which is the attempt to add `yield` to CoffeeScript. CoffyScript is *very* new and as i'm writing this i'm pondering over the difficulties posed by `require.extensions` being a global, and whether i should be a separate extension. that said, CoffyScript does work, and you will find on my github page numerous examples that show how to write quite succinct asynchronous code using `suspend`, `resume`, and `yield`.

given that `yield` has arrived in NodeJS 11.2, i believe we should research how to use generators / coroutines to make asynchronous programming more palatable. i for one have tossed out promises, the experience with them having not been so pleasant. Then again, it may take a while before `yield` becomes available in all major browsers.